# How to access orientDB docker-compose set cluster?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cluster-computing, orientdb

I am trying to set Orientdb cluster with docker, here is docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  odb1:
    image: orientdb:2.2.30
    command: dserver.sh
    volumes:
      - ./var/odb1/config:/orientdb/config
      - ./var/odb1/databases:/orientdb/databases
    environment:
      ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      ORIENTDB_NODE_NAME: odb1
    ports:
      - 2480:2480
      - 2424:2424

  odb2:
    image: orientdb:2.2.30
    command: dserver.sh
    volumes:
      - ./var/odb2/config:/orientdb/config
      - ./var/odb2/databases:/orientdb/databases
    environment:
      ORIENTDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      ORIENTDB_NODE_NAME: odb2
    depends_on:
      - odb1
```

It runs fine with

```
docker-compose up
```

Returns message:

```
odb2_1  | 2017-11-28 12:47:48:069 INFO  OrientDB Studio available at http://localhost:2480/studio/index.html [OServer]
```

But I can't access this url: "This connection was reset", although it worked fine for one node mode.
As well I did not found clear answer how to access cluster in console, except of [this](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/Tutorial-Run-the-console.html), but it does not work for docker container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described on [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/orientdb/), accessing the console can be done via:

```
docker run --rm -it orientdb /orientdb/bin/console.sh
```

Comment: That was helpful, although it runs separate container, I meant this: 

    `docker exec -it <container-name> /orientdb/bin/console.sh` (it works)
but GUI does not work still, may be GUI is available for cluster only in Enterprise Edition?

Comment: You can also try to exec into the existing container: `docker exec -it <container-name> bash` and then run `/orientdb/bin/console.sh`